# How to combine two model list to one model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, lambda

Please see code below :

```
public class NewsFilterModel
{
    public CtArticleDetail ArticleDetail { get; set; }

    public PcPage Page { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<NewsFilterModel> GetNewsFilterModelByTagNames(string tagNames, int status)
{
     var resultArticle = db.CtArticleDetail.Where(m => m.tagNames == tagNames);
     var resultPage  = db.PcPage.Where(m => m.tagNames == tagNames);
}
```

Can anyone please advice what the best way to combine two model to one model which is NewsFilterModel ?

What I am trying to achieve is:

NewsFilterModelList

```
1.Article1
2.Page1
3.Article2
4.Page2
5.Article3
6.Page3
```

I've ended this like below:

```
foreach (var item in pageResult)
            {
                resultList.Add(new NewsFilterModel { ArticleDetail = null, Page = item, Date = item.UpdatedOn.ToDateTime() });
            }

            foreach (var item in tempArticleList)
            {
                resultList.Add(new NewsFilterModel { ArticleDetail = item, Page = null, Date = item.LiveDate.ToDateTime() });
            }

            return resultList.AsEnumerable();
```

Anyone has better idea, please advice.

Comment: How do you know which `CtArticleDetail` goes with which `PcPage`?

Comment: There is no relation between PcPage and CtArticleDetail. So I guess I don't need to know.

Comment: So, given an enumerable of `CCArticleDetail` and `PcPage`, are those enumerables supposed to have a 1:1 ratio and make one model for each set? What happens when the sets have an unequal number of items? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I'm trying to produce a list page that contains ctArticle and pcpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Union to combine the result sets

```
var query1 = db.CtArticleDetail
    .Where(a => a.tagNames.Equals(tagNames))
    .Select(a => new NewsFilterModel() { ArticleDetail = a, Page = null });
var query2 = db.PcPage
    .Where(a => a.tagNames.Equals(tagNames))
    .Select(a => new NewsFilterModel() { ArticleDetail = null, Page = a });
var query3 = query1.Union(query2)
    //.OrderBy(a => a.Date); -- Order here
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As apperantly there is no releationship in your `CtArticleDetail` and `PcPage`, so you need to change your model.

```
public class NewsFilterModel
{
    public IEnmerable<CtArticleDetail> ArticleDetails { get; set; }

    public IEnmerable<PcPage> Pages { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public NewsFilterModel GetNewsFilterModelByTagNames(string tagNames, int status)
{
     var resultArticle = db.CtArticleDetail.Where(m => m.tagNames == tagNames);
     var resultPage  = db.PcPage.Where(m => m.tagNames == tagNames);

     var newsFilterModel = new NewFilterModel { ArticleDetails = resultArticle, Pages = resultPage };
     return newsFilterModel;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. this is perfect. But I need to return IEnumerable<NewsFilterModel> because that model list page has pagination. And the list needs to be mixed articledetail and pcpage based on Live date.